# Fatal error for setLastModifiedBy() in PHPExcel

Tags: php, phpexcel

In my current project I uesed PHPExcel 1.6.7, as per suggested i configured PHPExcel library with my projet, but when i try to export data into excel file then i got following error.

```
Fatal error: Call to a member function setLastModifiedBy() on a non-object in C:\wamp\www\xxx\site\dump.php on line 28
```

I have followinf code in dump.php

```
/** Error reporting */
error_reporting(E_ALL);

/** PHPExcel */
require_once ("Classes/PHPExcel.php");


/** PHPExcel_IOFactory */
require_once ("Classes/PHPExcel/IOFactory.php");

// Create new PHPExcel object
$objPHPExcel = new PHPExcel();

// Set properties
$objPHPExcel->getProperties()->setCreator("Maarten Balliauw")
 ->setLastModifiedBy("Maarten Balliauw")
 ->setTitle("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
     ->setSubject("Office 2007 XLSX Test Document")
 ->setDescription("Test document for Office 2007 XLSX, generated using PHP classes.")
 ->setKeywords("office 2007 openxml php")
 ->setCategory("Test result file");

// Add some data
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('B1', 'world!')
        ->setCellValue('C1', 'Hello')
        ->setCellValue('D1', 'world!');

// Miscellaneous glyphs, UTF-8
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0)
        ->setCellValue('A2', 'Miscellaneous glyphs')
        ->setCellValue('B2', 'test text');

// Rename sheet
$objPHPExcel->getActiveSheet()->setTitle('Simple');


// Set active sheet index to the first sheet, so Excel opens this as the first sheet
$objPHPExcel->setActiveSheetIndex(0);


// Redirect output to a client’s web browser (Excel5)
header('Content-Type: application/vnd.ms-excel');
header('Content-Disposition: attachment;filename="01simple.xls"');
header('Cache-Control: max-age=0');

$objWriter = PHPExcel_IOFactory::createWriter($objPHPExcel, 'Excel5');
$objWriter->save('php://output'); 
exit;
```

I checked all configuration settings & find all required files are included for this but still get this error. Please suggest me any suggestion if i done any wrong in this process.

Thank you.

Comment: You might consider updating the version of PHPExcel you're running - 1.6.7 is over 3 years old now: the latest version is 1.7.8 and there's been a lot of bugfixes in that time, and a lot of changes including fluent interface for elements like document properties

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look here:

http://www.auditbureau.org.au/a/Documentation/API/PHPExcel/PHPExcel_DocumentProperties.html#methodsetLastModifiedBy

setLastModfiedBy() returns void. Therefore, you can't chain call all the ->setXX calls you've been making. You should call each on the return value of getProperties() separately.